# Queries related to EJB3

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am new to EJB3.0 . I have some queries related to EJB.
Could some one help here.

1. Is it possible for EJB method to return another EJB ?
   Ex: Client using JNDI gets the reference of EJB and calls one method on it, which in turn can return another EJB ?
   (if possible any example )
2. As far as I know JNDI runs on some default port.
   is it possible to create JNDI on custom port and bind EJB to that ?
   can this be done using initial context parameters ?
     (if possible any example )
3. Suppose client invokes method on EJB, which port is used for that ?
   Is it the same port which client used to access JNDI ? or some another port ?

Thank you in advance

/kar

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.  Just declare the return value of the method to be the remote interface. The application server will do the rest.
2. Yes, just use (Initial)Context.bind. It's not clear why you would want to do this, and it's unlikely that most application servers will do this automatically.
3. In the case of RMI-IIOP, the host and port of the target EJB are encoded in the IOR of the remote stub. This is not necessarily the same as the host and port used to perform the lookup.  For example, on WebSphere Application Server, it is possible (though not necessarily recommended) to bootstrap JNDI against the host and port of a nodeagent process, which could return an EJB stub that contains a list of hosts and ports for several servers if the EJB is started on a cluster.